# How to get only specific fields from Mongodb document?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

From system.profile collection I have documents like this:

```
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "..",
    "command" : {
        "count" : "..",
        "query" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    "responseLength" : 48,
    "millis" : 18,
}
```

Some queries don't have the command field instead they have 'query' field. I want to check if 'command' field exist. If it does then append that to my Stringbuilder object, if not append 'query'.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to use Projection as suggested by Davide by but still I am not finding a way to checking if query exist, if it does then append that.

```
DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("system.profile");
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("command", new BasicDBObject("$exists",true));
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("command",1).append("millis", 1).append("ts", 1);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, fields);
 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(cursor.next());
    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
return sb;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the following [method](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-):

```
public DBCursor find(DBObject query, DBObject projection);
```

From [java doc](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-):

> **projection** - specifies which fields MongoDB will return from the documents in the result set.

Comment: The answer is correct for the title of the question!

Comment: I have tried to use Projection like you suggested. Can you see my update on my question? The only problem is I am able to get specific fields but I am not understanding how to make it work for checking if 'query' field exist. Whatever I am writing works if 'command' exist. If 'query' exist then there is no 'command' field.